# JavaScript regex spltting of string if keyword exists

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two possible example strings:

```
'Software Sheffield'
```

and

```
'Software IN Sheffield'
```

and I want to split the string if it has the keyword 'IN' in the middle of it.

So for example 1:

```
var string1 = 'Software Sheffield';

var string2 = '';
```

and for example 2:

```
var string1 = 'Software';

var string2 = 'Sheffield';
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

So far I have tried:

```
var string1 = string.split(/[ IN ]+/);

var string2 = string.split(/+[ IN ]/);
```

Comment: remove jquery wrapping.. it will work fine

Comment: @Mr_Green: No, it won't.

Comment: yeah it will not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[ IN ]+/` means "the individual characters `[SPACE]`/`I`/`N`/`[SPACE]` repeated 1 to inifinity times" so it'd also match "`NINININININIII NNNNIIINIIII`".

You can simply use a string in `split()`:

```
var splitter = string.split(' IN ');
var string1 = splitter[0];
var string2 = (splitter.length >= 2 ? splitter[1] : '');
```

Comment: That's working except that if one of them is empty I get undefined as the value of the string.

Comment: or simply `splitter[1] || ''`

Comment: @thg435 That'd work just as fine (the reason for this, OP, is that `splitter[1]`, if not set, would be `undefined` which is a falsy value. Therefore what this would say is "if splitter[1] is not falsy, then use splitter[1], but if it IS falsy, then use `''`".)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the string as separator (with spaces)

```
.split(' IN ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex - [ IN ] Means that it matches I letter and N letter.
Simply

```
string.split('IN');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use jQuery function here? Just work with string

```
'Software Sheffield'.split(' IN ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
 var strings = "Software IN Sheffield".split(" IN "); // this will be returning an array

 var string1 = strings[0];

 var string2 = strings[1];
```

check this http://jsbin.com/iKeCUnA/1/